# UICollectionView challenge: set height on the last cell to fit availabe space

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Can you solve the following problem: I have a UICollectionView with a fixed number of CollectionView Cells - but the hight of the devices change and I have to dynamically calculate the last(buttom) cell.

```
------
I: Cell 1
------
I: Cell 2
------
I: Cell 3, This cell has a dynamic hight
I
------
```

I have tried the following:

note: `let view = self.cells[indexPath.row]` is a fixed list of UIView that I add to the UICollectionView contextView in `cellForItemAt`

Also the code is in a class that implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
self.collectionView?.isScrollEnabled = false

    var totalHight: CGFloat = 0

    public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                               layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                               sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        let view = self.cells[indexPath.row]

        self.totalHight = self.totalHight + view.frame.size.height

        if (self.totalHight > self.frame.size.height){
            let diff = self.totalHight - self.frame.size.height
            let height = (view.frame.size.height - diff)

            view.frame.size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width,
                                     height: height)
            self.totalHight = 0
            return view.frame.size
        }else{
            return CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)
        }
}
```

Comment: Why not using a `UITableView` if you have only vertical content?
Else, the logic would be: `if indexPath.row == lastIndex {collectionView.frame.size.height - calculateAllThepreviousCellsSizesHeight = heightLastCell} else {//return fixedSize}` in pseudo code.

Answer (score 3):

I can't tell if that code you've tried is in your view controller or a custom layout. What was the result?

This *can* be done with a custom `UICollectionViewLayout` instance. You can probably get by with subclassing `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and overriding

```
collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:
```

Then you can look at the remaining space on the screen. It will probably pose problems if the content ends up exceeding the available space.

One approach you might look at is getting the layout attributes for the previous cell, and that will give you its frame, something like this:

```
let previousIndexPath = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row - 1, section: indexPath.section)
let attribs = layoutAttributesForItem(at: previousIndexPath)
let previousFrame = attribs.frame

let availableHeight = totalHeight - previousFrame.size.height
return CGSize(width: previousFrame.width, height: availableHeight)
```

See more here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/UsingtheFlowLayout/UsingtheFlowLayout.html

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewlayout/1617797-layoutattributesforitem

**Edit**: as an aside, it sounds like maybe using `UIStackView` and autolayout constraints would make this thing much easier, since your content is static and doesn't scroll.

Comment: Plus 1 for StackView - seems the perfect solution